# Populating column for Oracle Text search from 2 tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, full-text-search, text-search

I am investigating the benefits of Oracle Text search, and currently am looking at collecting search text data from multiple (related) tables and storing the data in the smaller table in a 1-to-many relationship.

Consider these 2 simple tables, house and inhabitants, and there are NEVER any uninhabited houses:

```
HOUSE
ID   Address          Search_Text
1    44 Some Road
2    31 Letsby Avenue
3    18 Moon Crescent

INHABITANT
ID   House  Name          Nickname
1    1      Jane Doe      Janey
2    1      John Doe      JD
3    2      Jo Smythe     Smithy
4    2      Percy Plum    PC
5    3      Apollo Lander Moony
```

I want to to write SQL that updates the HOUSE.Search_Text column with text from INHABITANT. Now because this is a 1-to-many, the SQL needs to collate the data in INHABITANT for each matching row in house, and then combine the data (comma separated) and update the Search_Text field.

Once done, the Oracle Text search index on HOUSE.Search_Text will return me HOUSEs that match the search criteria, and I can look up INHABITANTs accordingly.

Of course, this is a very simplified example, I want to pick up data from many columns and Full Text Search across fields in both tables.

With the help of a colleague we've got:

```
select id, ADDRESS||'; '||Names||'; '||Nicknames as Search_Text
  from house left join(
    SELECT distinct house_id,
      LISTAGG(NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY house_id) as Names,
      LISTAGG(NICKNAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NICKNAME) OVER (PARTITION BY house_id) as Nicknames
    FROM INHABITANT) 
  i on house.id = i.house_id;
```

which returns:

```
1    44 Some Road; Jane Doe, John Doe; JD, Janey
2    31 Letsby Avenue; Jo Smythe, Percy Plum; PC, Smithy
3    18 Moon Crescent; Apollo Lander; Moony
```

Some questions:

1. Is this an efficient query to return this data? I'm slightly
   concerned about the distinct.
2. Is this the right way to use Oracle Text search across multiple text fields?
3. How to update House.Search_Text with the results above? I think I need a correlated subquery, but can't quite work it out.
4. Would it be more efficient to create a new table containing House_ID and Search_Text only, rather than update House?

Comment: what you are exactly expecting already you have your query

Comment: @DaBozUK Performace depends upon the no of records in table. If you more worried, have to use table normalization

Comment: @Jonathan, there are 4 questions above, and while the SQL returns data, question 3 asks how to turn this into an update on HOUSE.